# How can I throw an exception for the whole class instead of doing it method by method

Tags: java, exception, throws

I'm writing a program in Java, and nearly every method in one of my classes is written like:

```
public void doStuff() throws AWTException{}
```

Is there a way for me to get rid of the extra step of typing throws AWTException for each method, and somehow do it for the entire class?

Comment: If you are using spring then its possible , but that is on application level but not on class level

Comment: Why don't you get your IDE to auto-fix these methods? Just about every IDE supports this. I wouldn't type them in by hand.

Comment: @ Peter: I'll have to look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sorry, No. There is no way to do this in Java.

Answer (score 3):

if you throw exception with class level then how you identify that on which type of exception is thrown by method... or on which method it throw exception.

so it is not allow in java...and also its not a good coding with java

Answer (score 1):

You can by throw exception at constructor level. You can see how FileInputStream force us to throw IO exception while creating object of it.