# Can a class throw an exception? or its just that only methods can throw exceptions?

Tags: java

Can a class throw an exception for example

```
class A throws Exception
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: A class cannot throw an exception (what sense would that make?); however, a class' _constructors_ can

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405940/how-can-i-throw-an-exception-for-the-whole-class-instead-of-doing-it-method-by-m